# Best Practice for Naming Symfony2/Doctrine Primary Keys

Tags: doctrine-orm, symfony

I'm migrating a site to Symfony2.  The site has tables where the primary key integer has a name, following the convention of table name + "id".  E.g. Table "Node" has primary key "nodeid".

On one hand, this means complex queries are easier to read and understand.  On the other, it is kind of a hassle to write a unique id name all the time, when Doctrine wants to use "id" for every table.

Is there a best practice or standard convention for naming primary keys in Symfony2/Doctrine2?  Thanks!

Comment: What are you using for entity configuration? Yml/annotation/xml?

Comment: Annotation.  I see the answer-- I didn't realize that Doctrine's entity property can have a different name.  Still, as a practice, I'm going to start using "id" as the primary key, and then table name + "_id" (e.g. node_id) when that primary key is used as a foreign key.  That seems to match up with Doctrine's documentation.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The name of the entity property is completely independent from the name of the column in database.

```
/**
 * @orm:Entity()
 * @orm:Table(name="custom_table_name")
 */
class Node {
    /** 
     * @orm:Id @orm:Column(type="integer", name="custom_id_name_eg_node_id")
     * @orm:GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id;
}
```

SQL query produced by `SELECT n.id FROM Node n;` DQL query:

```
SELECT u1.custom_id_name_eg_node_id FROM custom_table_name u1;
```

Comment: It doesn't answer the question. The author asks about the best practices. Can you post some links on official recomendations?